# Technique to find shared memory names currently used

Tags: linux, shared-memory

When one opens a shared memory object (using `shm_open`), you provide a name for that object.  Each object must have a distinct name.

Is there a way to identify the names of all of the currently allocated shared objects?  And if so, how?

**Update**: It would appear that, in my case, these are (as @HristoLliev calls them) System V shared memory segments.  `ipcs -m` reports a list of segments similar to what I expect, but does not show the names.

Comment: Can you try `ipcs -a`? (`-m` is for just shared memory).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: That lists the segments, but not the name associated with each.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`shm_open(3)` on Linux relies on `tmpfs`, usually mounted under `/dev/shm`. What `shm_open()` does is to convert the object name into a file path by prepending it with the mount point of the `tmpfs` filesystem. As long as the shared memory object is not unlinked, it will be visible in the filesystem and all you need to do is issue a simple `ls` command:

```
$ ls /dev/shm
pulse-shm-1   pulse-shm-2   pulse-shm-3
...
```

Some Linux distributions have `tmpfs` mounted under a different mountpoint. In order to find out where, issue:

```
$ mount -t tmpfs
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
```

If you want to know which process(es) has/have mapped shared memory objects, the `lsof` command is your friend:

```
$ lsof /dev/shm
COMMAND     PID     USER  FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
kded4     30657   hristo mem    REG   0,16 67108904 294877 /dev/shm/pulse-shm-1
kded4     30657   hristo mem    REG   0,16 67108904 294868 /dev/shm/pulse-shm-2
knotify4  30687   hristo mem    REG   0,16 67108904 294876 /dev/shm/pulse-shm-3
pulseaudi 30717   hristo mem    REG   0,16 67108904 294868 /dev/shm/pulse-shm-4
shm.x     31878   hristo DEL    REG   0,16          305893 /dev/shm/asd
```

Unlinked shared objects are no longer visible in the filesystem, though they might still persist if mapped in by some process as is the case with the last process in the list above - `DEL` in the `FD` field means that the corresponding file was deleted.

Note that System V shared memory segments (as obtained by `ipcs -m`) live in a different name space and do not have corresponding object names, just numeric keys.

Comment: @HristoLLiev: My `tmpfs` directory does not seem to contain any of the names I expect, and the list I get from `ipcs -m`, while it does not include the names, looks like the set of segments I expect.  So, as good as your answer is, it doesn't quite solve my problem.

Comment: System V IPC objects do not have names. They only have numeric keys and there is a convenience function `ftok()` that takes a file name and combines parts of the file's inode and device numbers with an additional 8-bit ID in order to produce a numeric key (see [here](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/sysvipc/ftok.c) how it's done). The function is not invertible and you cannot simply obtain the file name used to generate the key (since it keeps only the lower 16 bits of the inode number).